# Android AccountManager accounts storage

Tags: android, accountmanager, accounts

Where are the AccountManager Accounts stored? Is it on the device? If yes in which folder is it stored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is stored here:

```
Environment.getSystemSecureDirectory().getPath() + File.separator + DATABASE_NAME;
```

Where getSystemSecureDirectory:

> Gets the system directory available for secure storage. If Encrypted
>   File system is enabled, it returns an encrypted directory
>   (/data/secure/system). Otherwise, it returns the unencrypted
>   /data/system directory.

and `DATABASE_NAME = "accounts.db";`

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response!

Comment: on newer builds with multiple user profile support, you'll find the database at `/data/system/users/0/accounts.db`, replacing `0` with the actual user number.

Answer (score 1):

While the answer is perfectly correct, you should keep in mind that 'Environment.getSystemSecureDirectory()' is a platform API method and not part of the public SDK's API. If you look at its javadoc, you will realize the '@hide' annotation:

> ```
>  /**
>  * Gets the system directory available for secure storage.
>  * If Encrypted File system is enabled, it returns an encrypted directory (/data/secure/system).
>  * Otherwise, it returns the unencrypted /data/system directory.
>  * @return File object representing the secure storage system directory.
>  * @hide
>  */
> ```

The hidden methods are meant for use only by platform apps that are distributed along with the platform itself. They are compiled against the platform source rather than the SDK source as apps for Play/Market are required to be.

This means that you're not allowed to use it if you want to distribute your app on Play/Market.